# Firestore Event Trigger Fire Occurred Error Unhandled Rejection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm changing real time database to Firestore.
Using cloud function trigger onUpdate() always failed with error message.

here's my cloud function **index.js**

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");

const friendProcess = require("./friend_process");


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://projec-name.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.friendProcess = functions.firestore.document("users/{userId}/friends/{requestId}").onUpdate(friendProcess);
```

and this code is **friend_process.js**

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

module.exports = function(event) {
  const userId = event.params.userId;
  const updatedData = event.data.data();
  const requestId = updatedData.fromUid;
  const previousData = event.data.previous.data();
  console.log("update data", updatedData);
  console.log("requestId", requestId);
  console.log("userId", userId);

  if (previousData.status === "request" && updatedData.status === false) {
    console.log("updatedData.action  ", updatedData);
    console.log("ref", event.data.ref);
    
    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(requestId)
      .collection("friends")
      .doc(userId)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        return console.log("doc  ", doc);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return console.log("error  ", error);
      });
  }
  return;
};
```

here's my console log

[firebase console log link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ5eq.png)

> Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
>       at GoogleAuth. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:229:31)
>       at step (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:47:23)
>       at Object.next (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:28:53)
>       at fulfilled (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:19:58)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

my package.json
`"firebase-admin": "^5.11.0",`
`"firebase-functions": "^0.9.1",`